# My breadth first algorithm is not working properly

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I tried to do a breadth first algorithm. And this is what I have so far.

```
void BreadthFirst(int A[][100], int a, int nNodes)
{
// Local variables
// Queue of nodes Q
int visited[100];
for (int i = 0; i < nNodes; i++)
    visited[i] = 0; // initially all nodes are not visited
// Initialize Q to be empty
    int Q[100];
    int readPtr = 0, writePtr = 0;
    // Mark 'a' visited
    visited[a] = 1;
    // Write 'a'
    cout << char(a + 'a');
    // Enqueue (Q,a)
    Q[writePtr++] = a;
    // While 'a' is not empty do
    while (readPtr != writePtr)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < nNodes; n++)
        {
            if (A[n][readPtr] == 1)
            {
                // If 'n' is not visited
                if (visited[n] == 0)
                {
                    // Mark 'n' as visited
                    visited[n] = 1;
                    // Write 'n'
                    cout << char(n + 'a');
                    // enqueue (Q,n)
                    Q[writePtr++] = n;
                }
            }
        }
        readPtr++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I used the following graph to test it:

[image: Graph]

which has the following adjacency table:

[image: Adjacency table]

Using that table I wrote my main function:

```
int main()
{
int nNodes = 11;
int a = 0;
int A[][100] =
{
    { 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0 },
    { 1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0 },
    { 1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0 },
    { 0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1 },
    { 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1 },
    { 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0 },
};
BreadthFirst(A, a, nNodes);
return 0;
}
```

And it isn't working. The output should be

`abehicjkdfg`

Instead I get

`abehicdfgjk`

Can you help me fix it, please?

Comment: You shouldn't iterate on the nodes. You need to add the first node (a) to your queue, and then fill the queue with whatever nodes you discover. Your for loop should then just run untill it reaches the end of the queue (which grows larger and larger on every discovered node).

You also need to separate between the queue and the visited array. They are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not accessing the queue correctly in your while loop instead of `A[n][readPtr]` it should be `A[n][Q[readPtr]]` in this while loop

```
while (readPtr != writePtr)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < nNodes; n++)
    {
        if (A[n][Q[readPtr]] == 1)
        {
            // If 'n' is not visited
            if (visited[n] == 0)
            {
                // Mark 'n' as visited
                visited[n] = 1;
                // Write 'n'
                cout << char(n + 'a');
                // enqueue (Q,n)
                Q[writePtr++] = n;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion below line should be re-written,

```
 if (A[n][readPtr] == 1)
```

to

```
 if (A[Q[readPtr]][n] == 1)
```